# Duplicate a Safari tab along with associated browsing history (OS X)

Tags: keyboard, safari

Is there a way to duplicate a Safari (Safari 7 for OS X) tab and carry its browsing history to the duplicate? Like, when I do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> the copy has no history, as if I just pressed <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and pasted the URL of an existing tab.

Any suggestions on how to implement such a feature in case none exists will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nope. Chrome behaves as desired though.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution (yet), but fyi you might want to keep an eye on this, if it gets implemented: https://github.com/thiemo/duplicatetabbutton/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite what you want, but you can set the default tab behavior to be open with same page, which will preserve your history.

[image]